# How can you make an img element the same size and alignment as emojis or text?

Tags: html, css, svg

[image]

For some reason, no matter which `vertical-align` I use, the image is slightly under center from the text line. How do I match the size of the text? How do I match size of the emojis? How do I vertically center the image?

```css
body {
  color: #fff;
  background: #000;
}

svg {
  height: 1em;
  width: 1em;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<section>
<h1>
Emoji, image and size tests
</h1>
<p>
Notice in the following lines, the svg element (fullscreen icon) is not vertically aligned with the text, and its size isn't the same as the other square emojis.
</p>
<p>
  ABC<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="330" height="330" viewBox="0 0 87.312 87.312"><g fill="none" stroke="#fff" stroke-width="15.875"><path d="M34.396 79.375H7.937V52.917M52.917 79.375h26.458V52.917M34.396 7.938H7.937v26.458M52.917 7.938h26.458v26.458"/></g></svg>DEFG
</p>
<p>
  K▶️<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="330" height="330" viewBox="0 0 87.312 87.312"><g fill="none" stroke="#fff" stroke-width="15.875"><path d="M34.396 79.375H7.937V52.917M52.917 79.375h26.458V52.917M34.396 7.938H7.937v26.458M52.917 7.938h26.458v26.458"/></g></svg>K▶️
</p>

</section>
```

Comment: Use `svg{display:inline-block}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add paddding bottom, Ive tweaked the fiddle.

```
svg {
  height: 1em;
  width: 1em;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding-bottom:0.2em
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/6hd320f4/

Comment: This one looks great! Strangely though, it seems the `padding-bottom:0.2em` makes  the whole `<p>` taller instead of aligning the image with the rest of the text. https://imgur.com/a/pNgkj1Y

Comment: Inspired by this, I tried `position: relative; top: 0.153em;` and it does the trick. I'm going to guess this will depend on the font and emojis. I don't know if there's a consistent way to do this.

Comment: I think this might help you, its from 2009: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/absolute-center-vertical-horizontal-an-image/

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to use flexbox like this:

```
p {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

Don't forget `flex: wrap` in order to maintain the text line break.

Note: if you edit line-height and test different values, you will find a pixel inconsistency that is hard to avoid due to the fixed proportions.

Comment: you should not make a text container a flexbox container: https://jsfiddle.net/8zykfgr0/

Comment: It's also slightly misaligned still https://imgur.com/a/NpTX4dI result with lines. Code used at https://jsfiddle.net/ubershmekel/vxLrto21/

Comment: ubershmekel. That's why I commented about line-height. It's not very consistent in such small dimensions

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps counter-intuitive, but if you use `vertical-align: top;
  margin: 1px 0;` on the svg, it aligns correctly.

Comment: While this aligns nicely with text, it seems to get emoji alignment wrong. https://jsfiddle.net/ubershmekel/vxLrto21/ with the visual result at https://imgur.com/a/RyxcqxK

Answer (score 0):

Try `text-top` as value of `vertical-align`

```css
body {
  color: #fff;
  background: #000;
}

svg {
  height: 1em;
  width: 1em;
  vertical-align: text-top;
}
```

```html
<section>
<h1>
Emoji, image and size tests
</h1>
<p>
Notice in the following lines, the svg element (fullscreen icon) is not vertically aligned with the text, and its size isn't the same as the other square emojis.
</p>
<p>
  ABC<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="330" height="330" viewBox="0 0 87.312 87.312"><g fill="none" stroke="#fff" stroke-width="15.875"><path d="M34.396 79.375H7.937V52.917M52.917 79.375h26.458V52.917M34.396 7.938H7.937v26.458M52.917 7.938h26.458v26.458"/></g></svg>DEFG
</p>
<p>
  K▶️<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="330" height="330" viewBox="0 0 87.312 87.312"><g fill="none" stroke="#fff" stroke-width="15.875"><path d="M34.396 79.375H7.937V52.917M52.917 79.375h26.458V52.917M34.396 7.938H7.937v26.458M52.917 7.938h26.458v26.458"/></g></svg>K▶️
</p>

</section>
```

Comment: If you look closely, `text-top` is a bit higher than the text and emojis. See https://imgur.com/AHgf1SN